# Hosting MySQL connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using this script to connect to a database. But it is throwing me this exception. Need Help!

```
<?php
$servername = "xxxx";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=my_db", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

The exception :

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sites\mysql\index.php on line 8
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

Comment: **DO NOT POST YOUR CREDENTIALS**. It's time to change your password for this service.

Comment: doing it after this.. this is a test database

Comment: Maybe you think that's all someone can get but they can likely get a lot more than that one database. Always, always remove your credentials from any questions.

Comment: yeah my bad! wouldnt do it now

Comment: looks like `$servername` is wrong --for xampp one assumes it should be `localhost`

Comment: That error means it can't resolve the host name. Double check that you've put it in correctly. If possible, try to resolve it from the server you're running your PHP code on using `dig` or `nslookup`. It's possible your DNS settings are wrong on your PHP server which is blocking lookups.

Comment: nslookup gives a timed out response

Comment: for one of many possible reasons, your machine, cant connect to 'that' machine. Firewalls and router configs are a good place to start

Comment: Possible problems: `/etc/resolv.conf` has bogus entries. The name you've specified is at a domain that's not correctly configured. Your machine isn't allowed to make DNS queries because of firewall rules.

Comment: It's not a firewall issue, mysql.hostinger.in doesn't exist.

Comment: can anyone suggest a free mysql hosting site